# How to connect to a Nodejs server from outside the LAN

Tags: node.js, networking, nodejs-server

I’d like to connect to the raspberry Pi Node.js server I set up from outside my network.

My router claims the port is open. I have tried running the server at 127.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0, and at my public IP address.

I have tried using ngrok to open port 8080, where the server hosts a simple web page, but trying to access myIP:8080 doesn’t work.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

If you run ngrok on the raspberry pi itself, `ngrok http 8080` will work.

If you run ngrok on a device on the LAN but not the raspberry pi, you will need to find the LAN IP of the raspberry pi first before running `ngrok http <LAN IP>:8080` will work.